# Is it possible to prevent a process that is running in full screen mode from modifying mouse pointer movement?

Tags: windows, hardware

I am using the latest version of Windows 10 for this example.
The application, when in a certain state, prevents the mouse pointer from hitting the edge of the screen by making it invisible, centering it and always make it return to the original position when moved. This behaviour can be observed when running a simple python script in the background that monitors mouse movement. The mouse pointer only moves a few pixels into the direction in which it is dragged and then returns to the center of the screen.

The question is whether it is possible to have a program running in the background that prevents this sort of pointer manipulation and allows the mouse to move freely despite the main program being in the abovementioned state. 
The possibilities I see are to either somehow alter the running program (which would be very difficult given that it is already compiled into a binary file) or to have some script running in the background that can directly access the raw mouse input and calculate the correct cursor location at the given time.

My first attempt to achieve this was to detect and add up all the minor location changes of the cursor (which in this state is (960, 600), the middle of the screen) and then adding them to the cursor coordinates prior to entering this state. Here, the main program enters this centering state when the key 'v' is pressed:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import keyboard
from time import sleep
import win32api, win32con, win32ui
import numpy

keypress = False
key = 'v'
ww= False

while True:
    curpos = win32api.GetCursorPos()
    if ww:
        if curpos != (960, 600)):
            finalpos = numpy.add(finalpos, numpy.subtract(curpos,initpos))
            initpos = curpos    
    if keypress and not keyboard.is_pressed(key):
        sleep(0.01)
        win32api.SetCursorPos(finalpos)
        keypress = False
        pass
        ww= False
    elif keyboard.is_pressed(key) and not keypress:
        initpos = curpos
        finalpos = curpos
        keypress = True
        ww = True
```

However, this method turned out to be much too inaccurate for the intended use since the degree to which the cursor location is corrected is directly related to how quickly the script is reading the changes (if it were to be twice as fast then twice the changes would be recorded), so i do not see any way around somehow entirely circumventing this centering mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No

Long answer:

There are multiple way how to implement pointer lock. The naive way is to hide and recenter the cursor. You are effectively trying to counteract the effect of pointer lock. But applications that do pointer lock, like a game, it's a desired effect. So I don't understand why you would want to do it.

The problem you are facing is a race conditions, your script and the application are trying to change the same value; the mouse cursor position. The application that runs the fastest kind of wins, but the resulting behavior is a mess.

If the application that does the pointer lock is so annoying, why run it at the same time on the same machine. If you really need to run it in the background while using he system, why not use multiple virtual desktops and putting the application one desktop and then using the other.